# SQL in Java sending to two Tables but having errors

Tags: java, sql

***********************************SOLVED BY I-LOVE-2-REVIVE SEE BELOW********************

data base was throwing back error wen adding a "fileNo" as the other fields that went to default where dates and defualt was set to 0. so in access =Date() was set in default and Error was solved.thanks again all!

*********************************************END OF SOLUTION*****************************************

im having some serious trouble and my brain has completely melted on me trying to solve it!

so basically i have 2 tables in my access Database a "Files" Table containing FileNo,TrailDate,Clientname.
another Called "ToDO" containing 
FileNo, 1,1a,1b, 2,2a,2b ECT. (1 relates to Thing you need to do and 1a relates to the date it needs to be accomplished)

i then have 2 entry points on my java program.
one you enter a file. this sends to the file database and works fine!
the second pulls the "FileNo" column from "Files" to a Jcombo box and once you click that file Number searched the "ToDO" table for its data in 1,1a,2,2a ect. then outputs this so the user can edit or review.

my problem im having now is i need it so that when you input a new file in AddFile GUI to then add that FileNo to the "ToDO" Database as well.

this is a sample of the code im working with

```
try { //// WORKING  
       PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Files(FileNo,TrialDate,ClientName)VALUES('"+fileNumber+"','"+trialDate+"','"+clientName+"')");
            statement.executeUpdate();
            statement.close();
            connect.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File added to Database. Returning to main menu");
            System.out.println("Success!");
            adfFrame.setVisible(false);
            mainMenu();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File name already in Database!");
            System.out.println("Error" + ex);}
```

now when i change this code to :

```
try { 
       PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ToDO(FileNo)VALUES('"+fileNumber+"')");
                            statement.executeUpdate();
            statement.close();
            connect.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File added to Database. Returning to main menu");
            System.out.println("Success!");
            adfFrame.setVisible(false);
            mainMenu();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File name already in Database!");
            System.out.println("Error" + ex);}
```

i get a SQL exception reading: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: incompatible data type in conversion

But the thing is i don't understand how that can be possible!? as in my database design the FileNo in "TodO" Table is LongText as it is in "Files" Table i have no issues with the file input at all but the second i try to add the same data to ToDO i get error!

i am fairly new Java and this is my first full project so apologies if this is trivial but iv searched and searched and i cant find a suitable answer for my problem :(

.......EDIT....

this the all the code for the method.

```
   private void fileFrame() {    
    //POPULATES CLIENTS STRING ARRAY 

    String[] clients= new String[noclients];
    String sql1 = "SELECT ClientName FROM ClientTable";
        try {
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql1);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    System.out.println(sql1);
    int count= 0;           
        try {
            while (rs.next()){
                clients[count] = rs.getString("ClientName");
                count = count + 1; 
                System.out.println("Clients="+clients);
            }   } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
//FINISHES CLIENT ARRAY POPULATION.        
    JLabel l = new JLabel("File Reference");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Trial Date");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JComboBox clientList = new JComboBox(clients);

    JButton b = new JButton("Save");
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Save and Exit");



        adfFrame.setSize(500,800);
        adfFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        adfFrame.setLocation(700, 500);
        adfFrame.setVisible(true);
        //Adds TExt Fields/Labels/Button to the GUI
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(l);
        p.add(t);
        p.add(l1);
        p.add(t1);
        p.add(clientList);
        p.add(b);
        p.add(b1);

        adfFrame.add(p);     
        p.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);

        //save button pressed
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //##DECLARES FILEPATH##
            String filePath = "C://Users/Chris/java/Tutorials GUI/2.Login page with Database/Login1/Login1.accdb";

            //##PULL FILEPATH FROM ABOVE##
            String db = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+filePath;
            Connection connect = null;
            try {
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
                /// CONNECTION  MADE
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            String fileNumber=t.getText();
            //System.out.println(fileNumber);
            String clientName=clientList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //System.out.println(clientName);
            String trialDate =t1.getText();
            //System.out.println(trialDate);


            try { //// WORKING  
           PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Files(FileNo,TrialDate,ClientName)VALUES('"+fileNumber+"','"+trialDate+"','"+clientName+"')");
          System.out.println("1");
           statement.executeUpdate(); 
           System.out.println(statement);
           statement.close();
                //statement.setString(1,clientName);
                //statement.setString(2,yn);
           //PreparedStatement stotement = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ToDO [FileNo] VALUES('"+fileNumber+"')");
          //System.out.println("2");
          //stotement.executeUpdate(); System.out.println(stotement);
               // stotement.close();
                connect.close();
                System.out.println("Success!");

            }catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File already in Database!");
                System.out.println("Error" + ex);
            }



            t.setText("");
            t1.setText("");
            fcount();
        }
    });

        //Save and exit button pressed
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //##DECLARES FILEPATH##
            String filePath = "C://Users/Chris/java/Tutorials GUI/2.Login page with Database/Login1/Login1.accdb";

            //##PULL FILEPATH FROM ABOVE##
            String db = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+filePath;
            Connection connect = null;
            try {
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
                /// CONNECTION  MADE
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            String fileNumber=t.getText();
            //System.out.println(fileNumber);
            String clientName=clientList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //System.out.println(clientName);
            String trialDate =t1.getText();
            //System.out.println(trialDate);


            try { //// WORKING  
           PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Files(FileNo,TrialDate,ClientName)VALUES('"+fileNumber+"','"+trialDate+"','"+clientName+"')");

                statement.executeUpdate();
                statement.close();
                connect.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File added to Database. Returning to main menu");
                System.out.println("Success!");

            }catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File name already in Database!");
                System.out.println("Error" + ex);
                adfFrame.setVisible(false);
                mainMenu();


            }

try { 
           PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ToDO(FileNo)VALUES('"+fileNumber+"')");
                statement.executeUpdate();
                statement.close();
                connect.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File added to Database. Returning to main menu");
                System.out.println("Success!");

            }catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File name already in Database!");
                System.out.println("Error" + ex);

         }

            t.setText("");
            t1.setText("");
            fcount();

        }
    });

}
```

in the above please note i have 2 buttons doing the same thing. B and B1 B1 usually has a GUI Exit on it as a save and exit sort of deal.
 there may be some miner errors in this code please ignore those as i have very quickly edited it befor i ran out the door to work and posted here.

thanks again for looking :)

Comment: Are you sure you are sanitizing the filename? Does it contain ' in it if yes then you need to escape it

Comment: im also wondering if it may be worth me having another method where i compare the 2 tables on FileNo. and if ToDO does not have one of the file numbers to add it. but alas i am not that advanced in SQL code to figure out how to do that!

Comment: Pratik, the fileNumber is taken from a Jtextfield earlier in the method (String fileNumber=t.getText(); "t being the textfield") and as i say that worked fine for the Files SQL and i am using the exact same String to send to ToDO so i cant see how there can be a problem there?

Comment: @Chris_livermore Can you show us the full error? Are the rest of the fields in the ToDo table all nullable? Try run ("INSERT INTO ToDO(FileNo,1,1a,1b,2,2a,2b ECT)VALUES('"+fileNumber+"',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)")

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE that litterally is the full error its just that 1 thing all the other fields in ToDO are nullable, the only thing i could think is that i do have the database input a set date this is just a 0 call on the default. ill post the whole code above but be warned its really messy!

Comment: @Chris_livermore I think the error comes from converting the default 0 to a date/timestamp.. whatever you have on that column set to. Can you change it to DEFAULT GETDATE()

Comment: @Chris_livermore forget that last part. Your are using MSAcess.. you could use default =Date()

Comment: Could be that actually yeah I will try sometime tomorrow and report back. Cheers for help will let you know.

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE You where right!! i firstly tested on a blank Database with just fileNo fields in. this worked fine so i worked from there adding =Date() to all the date fields and its fixed itself it put a few other things out (as i had a few if statements checking for todays date) but i just sorted it all out so now my program is slightly less clunky! with fewer errors and repeats! so thanks alot of that! you have been a great help! and i have now learned a little more about database management :D thanks again!!

Comment: I-LOVE-2-REVIVE if you would like to add a reply to this post i will give you a correct answer up mate as i cant give rep yet as im only on 3 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error came from having an invalid default value on a date field. MsAccess does not recognise 0 as a valid date and results in a type conversion error. Use `default =Date()` a valid date or no default value to fix